# How can I fetch JSON data from a PHP file using Swift 2.1 and Xcode?

Tags: php, mysql, json, xcode, swift2

I've been trying to pull data from one of my databases to display on a mobile app that I am making using swift 2.1 and Xcode. I have a mysql database that is set up and a php script running from my server that echo's JSON encoded data from that database.

My swift application can post data to the PHP script and send data to the database, but I can't get data from the PHP script to display on the application. I have tried most of the methods, but they don't seem to work for the latest version of swift.

Here is my code:

```
func dataOfJson(url: String) -> NSArray {
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    let result: NSArray = []
    do {
        let json = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments]) as? NSDictionary)

        if let parseJSON = json {
            let resultValue = parseJSON["id"] as? String?
            print(resultValue)
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return result
}
```

And my PHP file's echoed result looks like this:

```
[{"id":"alex"},{"id":"jeff"},{"id":"jack"}]
```

How can I pull that JSON data and store it in swift variables?

Comment: Kindly convert data object to String and print it and add it here to see the response returned by the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
func dataOfJson(url: String) -> Array<Dictionary<String,String>>? {

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    do {

        let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments]) as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>>

        print("json := \(jsonArray)")
        return jsonArray;

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil;
    }
}
```

**I have tested with below code, working fine.**

```
let string = "[{\"id\":\"alex\"},{\"id\":\"jeff\"},{\"id\":\"jack\"}]";

let data = (string as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments]) as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>>

print("json := \(jsonArray)")

for object in jsonArray! {
            print("id := \(object["id"])");
}
```

Comment: i am also having issues with json from php. In your solutions where do you use func dataOfJson in your testing code/

Comment: I have just tested lines of functions in 2nd part of my code, not function by calling it, i have tested using dummy string, which you have provided after "And my PHP file's echoed result looks like this:"

Comment: if your php code will return json like "[{"id":"alex"},{"id":"jeff"},{"id":"jack"}]",it will perfectly work,

Comment: ah i see in swift my parsed json  looks like `Test vData: Optional((
        {
        visitorStreet = street;
        visitorPhone = 01606478;
        visitorCompany = xyl;
        
        visitorBranche = Sports;
        visitorEmail = "health@gmail.com";
        lastmodified = "2014-12-15 14:18:55";
    }
))` i am going to take a closer look into my php json file?? btw i am not the TS

Comment: My php json  file spits out `[{"scan_status":"ok","visitorData":[{"visitorCompany":"xyl","visitorStreet":"street","visitorBranche":"health","visitorEmail":"wesweatyoushop@gmail.com","lastmodified":"2014-12-15 14:18:55"}]}]` which i parse in swift with let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"] . My php json file looks fine too me, do you see where i go wrong?

Comment: update json string to your question, so I can update my answer based on question